# React Redux Authentication with JWT

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, jwt

I am trying to learn how security works in react redux applications

Here is a sample reducer code

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGOUT_SUCCESS
} from './actions'

function auth(state = {
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? true : false
  }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: action.creds
      })
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        errorMessage: ''
      })
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: action.message
      })
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

How secure is the local storage. Can someone on the client side(browser) tamper the token in local storage?

Also I am using a boolen isAuthenticated to be used through out the application. Is it possible to bypass the security by manually setting it to true somehow on the browser?

Can someone point me to any patterns that offer good security. Here is the flow I am thinking to implement

1. React App hits an API with user credentials to get a JWT. Is there a recommendation on how to encode the user credentials over network and decode them in API
2. API creates a JWT and sends it back to react App. What is a good pattern for saving and accessing the JWT
3. Can I store JWT in local storage? Is cookie a better option?

Comment: Yes, anyone can access localstorage.  You have to make sure you're validating the token each time you make a request to your server on the server.  It's important to code with the idea that user's can access anything stored inside your jwt, so only store data that will not cause a breach in security inside your jwt (Never send passwords or any data you don't want stolen).

Comment: About where to store the token, I would suggest taking a look at this article as storing it in a cookie or in local storage comes with their own sets of pros+cons.  It's up to the dev to decide which method of storage suits them best. https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: Also, AFAIK noone can access redux and change values from the browser.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's better to store in cookies with the HttpOnly flag because they are not accessible through JavaScript, and are immune to XSS. You can also set the Secure cookie flag to guarantee the cookie is only sent over HTTPS